# Android LinearLayout built-in button alignment?

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

i wanted if someone could clarify/approve one small thing:
When a `LinearLayout` contains two buttons (i didn't tested with more buttons), that are next to each other, then, if the height of one button is changed, the `LinearLayout` will always change the vertical position of the other button, so that the button texts are on one horizontal level?

Comment: The best way would be to check but if I understand the question - the answer is YES

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarilly. It depends on the gravity attribute of the LinearLayout.

If you have the gravity set to center vertical and height to wrap content, then the smaller button will remain in the same position, regardless of the size of the other one. Now, if the gravity is set to either top or bottom, the smaller button will stick to the top or bottom edge of the parent LinearLayout, as the other button is bigger and causes the parent to wrap it (of course, assuming the LinearLayout's height is set to wrap content).